# Given $\leq$ instead of $<$, show sequence convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

That is, let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence such that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $$|x_n - x| \leq \epsilon\text{.}$$
Then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x_n = x$.

My thoughts: my gut instinct is that if there is an $N$ for which this is true, there is probably an $N^{\prime} > N$ such that for all $n \geq N^{\prime}$, $|x_n - x| < \epsilon$. So perhaps I should look at the tail sequence $\{x_{n + \Delta}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ where $\Delta = N^{\prime} - N$. [One of the theorems available is that the tail sequence converges if and only if the entire sequence converges.]

Another approach I was considering is to assume by contradiction that $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x_n \neq x$$
but I wasn't sure where to go from here.

**Hints** are appreciated; I don't need a complete solution.

Comment: Think about $\epsilon / 2$.

Comment: hint: "... for **every** $\epsilon>0$"

Comment: @drhab HAHA, is it really just $|x_n - x| \leq \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon$???

Comment: "eureka" in second person (forgotten).

Comment: @drhab: Ἔυρηκας, I think.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you. I have quite some trust in your thinking. You earned that yourself ;-). *Eigen verdienste* in my language.